# How to find ratio on column of Dataframe

Tags: sql, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have loaded CSV into the data frame and using SPARK SQL to perform the operation.

I have column name decision which has "right" or "wrong" values.

I want to find out the ratio of right decision/Total decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet uses spark sql to get the ratio of the right decision..

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"right"),(2,"right"),(3,"right"),(4,"wrong"))).toDF("col1","col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: string]

scala> df.registerTempTable("test_table")
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details

scala> spark.sql("""SELECT sum(CASE WHEN col2 = "right" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/count(*) as percentage FROM test_table""").show()
+----------+
|percentage|
+----------+
|      0.75|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for solution